# Getting the latest day without a record containing that date

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-queryset

I'm trying to build a view which shows a list of timetables, each of which has 'availability' slots which contain a `from_datetime` and a `to_datetime`. I'm trying to find the latest 'availability' slot with no empty days between the that slot and the first. So, for example:

```
Date   Has availability slot
1/1    Yes
2/1    Yes
3/1    Yes <---- This is the date I'd like to return
4/1    No
5/1    Yes
6/1    Yes
7/1    No
```

Previously I was just annotating the `Max` of the availability slots onto each timetable, but that would return `7/1` in this case. I'd like a fast way of returning it. I currently have an implementation where I iterate through all the (ordered) slots for a timetable, wait until I find an empty day and return the slot just before that day. However this is very slow at the moment. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe slicing the dataframe on the test column and then applying min on the index to get the first empty slot?

```
    import pandas as pd
    import random

    index = pd.date_range('01/01/2005', periods = 12, freq = 'A')
    #to get a random list with booleans
    data = [True] + [bool(random.getrandbits(1)) for x in range(11)] 
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, index  = index, columns = ['Test'])
    #finds the first non True slot and gets all the previous items
    result = df.loc[:min(df[df.Test == False].index)].ix[:-1,:]
    print df, result

                Test
    2005-12-31  True
    2006-12-31  True
    2007-12-31  True
    2008-12-31  True
    2009-12-31  False
    2010-12-31  True
    2011-12-31  True
    2012-12-31  True
    2013-12-31  True
    2014-12-31  False
    2015-12-31  False
    2016-12-31  True

                Test
    2005-12-31  True
    2006-12-31  True
    2007-12-31  True
    2008-12-31  True
```